# NodeJS process.spawn - exit event not firing

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use nodejs process spawn. but somehow I'm not able to make it work. I use node v0.12.2.
The "gulp do-something" gets executed and I do see the output through stdout.. but exit event never gets executed!

```
var task = spawn('gulp', [
      'do-something'
], {
        cwd: configs.workingDirectory
});

task.stdout.on('data', function(data){
      console.log(data.toString());
});

task.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
});

task.on('exit', function (exitCode) {
        console.log("process.exitCode", exitCode)
});
```

when I try to use spawn with stdio: ['ipc']

```
var task = spawn('gulp', [
          'do-something'
    ], {
            cwd: configs.workingDirectory,
            stdio: ['ipc']
    });
```

the exit event gets fired but after the error:

```
gulp: ../deps/uv/src/unix/core.c:833: uv__io_stop: Assertion `loop->watchers[w->fd] == w' failed.
```

I tried other combinations for stdio. It causes either task.stdout and task.sterr to be null or exit event to be not fired..

Comment: Does `close` get emitted?

Comment: @mscdex no it does not.

Comment: ok. I managed to get it working using: stdio: [0, 'pipe', 'pipe']

Comment: You might also instead try `task.stdin.end();` with your original code.

Answer (score 3):

setting `stdio: [0, 'pipe', 'pipe']` solved the problem!!